# Hide first element when hovering on second element with CSS

Tags: css, html

On my page [www.damianhunkeler.ch](http://www.damianhunkeler.ch/) I have implemented a hover effect with CSS, when hovering on the names below the pics. The first child LI element is being shown on the page. When hovering on the other names, then the first element is currently being "covered" by the the eg. 2nd li element. That's bascially fine, except that the first small (10px) light-blue border right below the name is not being hidden when hovering on the second, thrid, etc. element.

Is there a way to hide the first li element when hovering on the others?

My current html code looks like this

```
<div class="mensch-img">
<ul>
    <li><img src="images/georges_theiler1.png"></li>
    <li><img src="images/yvonne_ruckli1.png"></li>
    <li><img src="images/mark_bachmann1.png"></li>
    <li><img src="images/rudei_staeger1.png"></li>
    <li class="last"><img src="images/josef_kreyenbuehl.png"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Georges<br>Theiler</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="slogan1"><a href="#">... weil er sich in der politischen Debatte durchzusetzen weiss. Das hat er als finanzpolitischer Leader der FDP-Fraktion im Kantonsrat bewiesen.<br><span class="small">STAENDERAT | LUZERN</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Yvonne<br>Ruckli</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="slogan1"><a href="#">... weil er geradlinig ist und konsequent liberal politisiert.<br>Ganz wie wir Jungfreisinnige.<br><span class="small">PRAESIDENTIN JUNGFREISINNIGE STADT LUZERN</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Mark<br>Bachmann</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="slogan1"><a href="#">... weil er ein erfahrener Unternehmer ist und weiss, was es braucht,<br>um den Kanton Luzern wirtschaftlich voran zu bringen.<br><span class="small">UNTERNEHMER | LUZERN</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Ruedi<br>Staeger</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="slogan1"><a href="#">... weil er durch und durch ein Sportsmann ist.<br>Das wirkt sich positiv auf seine Art zu politisieren aus.<br><span class="small">PRAESIDENT FC LUZERN</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="last">
        <a href="#">Josef<br>Kreyenbuehl</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="slogan1"><a href="#">... weil unsere Politik Leute braucht, die geerdet sind, <br>aber auch offen für Neues. Damian Hunkeler ist beides.<br><span class="small">PRAESIDENT BAECKERMEISTERVERBAND LUZERN</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my CSS like this:

```
.mensch-img img {
border: 1px solid #0c51a0;
border-bottom:none;
border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
}

.mensch-img ul{
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.mensch-img ul li{
float: left;
width: 122px;
text-align: center;
margin-right:17px;
margin-top:-4px;
}

.mensch-img ul li.last{
float:right;
margin-right:0px;
}

.mensch-img ul li a {
height:40px;
display: block;
padding: 6px 0px 0px 0px;
color: #fff;
background: #0c51a0;
text-decoration: none;
font-family:'MS-Light';
font-size:0.9375rem;
font-size:15px;
}

.mensch-img ul li a:hover{
color: #fff;
}

.mensch-img ul li ul{
display: none;
}

.mensch-img ul li:first-child ul {
display:block;
}

.mensch-img ul li:first-child ul li a{
background: #009EE3;
height:10px;
}

.mensch-img ul li:hover ul{
display: block;
}

.mensch-img ul li:hover ul li a {
background: #009EE3;
height:10px;
}

.mensch-img ul li:hover ul li.slogan1 a{
background: #009EE3;
height:65px;
width:71%;
position:absolute;
left:29%;
padding-top:10px;
line-height:130%;
font-size:0.875rem;
font-size:14px; 
}


.mensch-img ul li:first-child ul li.slogan1 a{
background: #009EE3;
height:65px;
width:71%;
position:absolute;
left:29%;
padding-top:10px;
line-height:130%;
font-size:0.875rem;
font-size:14px; 
}   


.small {
font-size:0.75rem;
font-size:12px;
font-family:'MS-LightCond';
letter-spacing:1px;
}
```

Any tipp on how achiving this (if possible at all with CSS) is of course highly appreciated...
Many Thanks, Chris

Comment: i dont think there is a css only direct way to do this. may be you can go for some workarounds, like adding a white color block to every other li:hover (except the first), which appears in the first li spot over the blue color box of the first li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with CSS alone with your current markup - there is no way of matching a preceding sibling. The only sibling selector I am aware of matches the direct following sibling - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

So either use js or you could create a pseudo child element of all the other li elements except the first, make the ul position relative and then position your child element's absolutely to cover the blue border on the first li.

```
ul {
  position: relative;
}
li:first-child {
  /* As is */
}
li:nth-child(n+2):hover::before { /* Will select all but the first */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 10px; /* You'll need to adjust this to suit */
  width: 100%; /* You'll need to adjust this to suit */
  background: #FFF;
}
```

This will work as long as your sizes are fixed, but it is using magic numbers for the height so js may be a better solution.